# Simba Athena ODBC: unable to use SQLGetPrivateProfileString functions

Tags: r, odbc, simba

This is very strange, I want to setup a connection from RStudio to my instance in AWS Athena.

I am using `unixodbc` as the driver manager, and succeded by testing the connection using `isql -v 'Simba Athena'`. However, when I test the connection in RStudio with...

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(
  odbc::odbc(),
  "Simba Athena"
)
```

... it gives me the error `Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [Simba][ODBC] (11560) Unable to locate SQLGetPrivateProfileString function.`. Any clue about it, I am a bit stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is basically not finding the correct ODBC driver. Simba by default references the driver in its `/Library/simba/athenaodbc/lib/simba.athenaodbc.ini` setup file to `libodbc.dylib` but it should be `libodbcinst.dylib`. At least in MacOS.

This solved my problem.

Comment: In my case, there wasn't a default value even set, so I had to add the following line. Also worth noting that I had to specify the full path; the combination of the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable with the filename alone did **not** work -
`ODBCInstLib=/usr/local/iODBC/lib/libiodbcinst.dylib`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I link with static library of "libodbc.a", however I can succeed to connect when I change to link with dynamic library of "libodbc.so"

Comment: Could you explain me how you did this?