# Simba Athena ODBC Driver: Can't Connect on a Mac

Tags: r, odbc, amazon-athena

I'm trying to connect to AWS Athena using Simba Athena ODBC in r.

```
DBI::dbConnect(
odbc::odbc(),
driver = "Simba Athena ODBC Driver",
S3OutputLocation   = <>,
AwsRegion          = "us-east-2",
AuthenticationType = "IAM Credentials",
Schema             = <>,
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = <>,
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = <>)
```

`Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [Simba][ODBC] (11560) Unable to locate SQLGetPrivateProfileString function: [Simba][DSI] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the error message for key 'LibsLoadErr' with message parameters ['""'] and component ID 3: Message not found in file "/Library/simba/athenaodbc/ErrorMessages/en-US/ODBCMessages.xml"`

I've updated my ODBC driver to route to the correct file per this question - [Simba Athena ODBC: unable to use SQLGetPrivateProfileString functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65336260/simba-athena-odbc-unable-to-use-sqlgetprivateprofilestring-functions)

I am also getting a response from the odbc:odbcListDrivers() function:

```
name                      attribute                    value   
ODBC Drivers              Simba Athena ODBC Driver     Installed
Simba Athena ODBC Driver  Description.                 Simba Athena ODBC Driver
Simba Athena ODBC Driver  Driver.                      /Library/simba/athenaodbc/lib/libathenaodbc_sb64.dylib
```